# Is the word "cloths" still used?

Tags: word-usage

[A user on an ESL forum](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic5267.html#13486) says,

> Cloths are pieces of fabric — for instance, washcloths or tablecloths.
>
> Clothes are wearing apparel — shirts, pants, etc.

Is this correct? And do we still use the word *cloths*? I’ve never seen it before.

— [Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cloth,clothes,cloths&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,cloth;,c0;.t1;,clothes;,c0;.t1;,cloths;,c0). PS. How is *Ngram* pronounced? N-gram?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, we still use it, and yes, it is usually a piece of cloth or fabric, typically with a specific use.  As you see from your own examples, we use it more often as the plural of a compound word such as washcloth, dishcloth, or tablecloth.

For an example of the use of the word on its own, google "burp cloths".  You will find all sorts of them for sale; burp cloths are cloths (pieces of cloth) that you can put on your shoulder while you're burping your baby, so he won't spit up on your clothes.

You can also use "cloths" to mean different kinds of cloth, as in "We have several cloths that will fit your needs" or "our hand-tailored shirts use only the finest cotton cloths from Egypt".  Saying "cloths" instead of "cloth" here implies that there is more than one type of finest cotton cloth coming from Egypt.  However, in this situation, "fabrics" is probably a bit more often used nowadays.

p.s. "EN-gram" is how I pronounce Ngram.

Comment: _You can also use "cloths" to mean different kinds of cloth, as in "We have several cloths that will fit your needs" or "our hand-tailored shirts use only the finest cotton cloths from Egypt"._  **Absolutely not.**  Speaking as somebody who has probably vastly more experience in fabric stores both "cloth" and "fabric" are used as collective nouns in that context.  "We have several kinds of cloth that will fit your needs" or "our hand-tailored shirts use only the finest cotton cloth from Egypt".  Native speakers do **not** use "cloths" (or "fabrics") in this way.

Comment: I find numerous examples of "cotton cloths" in the Ngram viewer.  For example [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZTo1tALvvEsC&pg=PA79&dq=%22cotton+cloths%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vv90U46NLI7hsAS9mII4&ved=0CGYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22cotton%20cloths%22&f=false) and [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=KjMUP2OyzMYC&pg=PA375&dq=%22cotton+cloths%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OgB1U8iUF8TgsASD6YL4BA&ved=0CEoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22cotton%20cloths%22&f=false).  There are plenty of others, so I'm afraid I have to disagree, your experience notwithstanding.

Comment: @Codeswitcher: What Bob said. I think it's quite possible things are slowly moving in the direction of your perspective, but I very much doubt it's anywhere near a *majority* position yet.

Comment: @BobRodes I just put "cotton cloths" into Google Books, and of the front page results, the most _recent_ is 1921, _most_ are from before 1900, and **all** of them are discussing imports. If you want to argue that in the import industry it's still the case that the archaic "cotton cloths" is in use as a term of art, make your case. Both your examples, though recent, are also about importation of fabric as a trade good, and were written by non-native speakers.

Comment: Furthermore, Ngram is useless for this, because "cotton cloths" is a perfectly correct phrase in your first usage, and Ngram can't distinguish between the two usages.  Ngram is going to count every example of "cotton cloths for polishing" and "cotton cloths for diapers" towards that count, which tells us nothing about your proposed usage.

Comment: [Here. QED.](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1333&bih=812&tbm=shop&q=%22cotton+cloths%22&oq=%22cotton+cloths%22")

Comment: You haven't demonstrated anything except that the other usage exists, which I freely grant.

Comment: [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=V91RAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA142&dq=%22cotton+cloths%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XBh1U8vdFovLsQTuqYLgDA&ved=0CFsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22cotton%20cloths%22&f=false) is one by a guy named Geoffrey Timmins from 1993, which is not talking about imports at all.  [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=2Qi8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22cotton+cloths%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9Rl1U4vvCInNsQTd94KgCA&ved=0CEcQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22cotton%20cloths%22&f=false) is another by one Frances Collier, in 1964, which discusses the manufacture of cotton in the 19th century.

Comment: As for "Ngram viewer", you're quite right, but for some reason the one I have on this machine returns a list of books rather than a graph. The list I'm using is [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cotton%20cloths%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1939,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&safe=active).

Comment: As far as "making my case", it is you who said that native speakers do not use the term in this way. Seeing as I've provided evidence that appears to refute that position, it looks to me like you're the one who has a case to make, not me. Of course, if you actually meant that "native speakers do not use the term in this way except in the import industry as an archaic term of art", then maybe you'd like to make that clear. That's getting a bit convoluted, though. It might just be easier to say "gee, maybe I was wrong", mightn't it?  I did, and look at all the interesting stuff I found.

Comment: When words can be used as mass nouns (that is, when you can say, _"Look at all that ____!"_) then the plural form general sits at the [bottom of the Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cloth%2Ccloths%2Cequipment%2Cequipments%2Crice%2Crices&year_start=1940&corpus=15). For example, we might say, "Look at all those cars! Look at all those birds!" But we don't usually say, "Look at all those equipments! Look at all those cloths!" Words like _waters, cloths_ and, _rices,_ are bona fide words, but aren't common, because the singular form often works better, even in a plural context.

Comment: From [The Cambridge History of Western Textiles](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cloths%2C+made+from+hemp+as+well+as+flax+osnaburgs%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), published 2003:- *Coarse cloths, made from hemp as well as flax - **osnaburgs, dowlas, ravenducks, hessians, buckrams, canvas, sailcloth** - were the speciality of the areas*. I don't have any specialist knowledge of the terminology used by fabric store workers, but it's pretty obvious to me those highlighted terms are all **cloths** in the sense "types of cloth", not "pieces of cloth".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I looked up all of the ones that were a plural, and they all mean some sort of cloth used in making one thing or another.  So, it's pretty obvious to me as well.

Comment: I'm not so presumptuous as to attempt to speak for all English speakers, whether English or not, but I know that saying "cloths" within the contexts listed by Bob would not result in raised eyebrows, at least in the part of England where I live (Home Counties), whether in common usage or in a fabric shop.

Comment: cloths is like grasses in that example. perfectly acceptable and commonly used in england. btw I am a native english speaker

Answer (score 1):

At least State-side, we don't really say 'cloths' in the context of 'the finest cloths from Egypt'. Instead we say fabrics. 'The finest cloth from Egypt is used, however.

Cloths are pieces of material, as you said, like washcloths or can even mean 'a pile of cloths,' as in a pile of rags or assorted cloths sitting around.

Comment: Then what should I call the pile of cloths that I keep in my kitchen, for wiping things up with?

Comment: Moreover, [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cloth) gives "cloths" as the plural of "cloth".  I don't understand how you can assert that it doesn't exist in American English.

Comment: @DavidWallace I think the issue is that while we all agree that individual items that are made of cloth--such as washcloths, dishcloths "burp cloths" as in my example and so on--have a plural of "cloths", there seems to be some disagreement on the idea that various types of cloth are called cloths.  As I said in my answer, we would more often use "fabrics" in this situation.  However, I disagree with the assertion that we do not also use "cloths" to mean this; I have cited many examples that would seem to refute it.

Comment: @JFA with regard to "for plural we use another word, such as fabrics", do you come to your conclusion after reading my examples?  If so, perhaps you will share your reasoning.  Please understand that it is with an open mind that I invite you to do this.

Comment: I think perhaps I misread something. I read "the finest cloths from Egypt" somewhere, and we don't really say that in the States, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @JFA While I don't have examples of the exact string you mention, I find enough related examples in the books in my link that I would say we really do say that in the states.  Again, though, the more common word in this context is fabrics, probably because we Americans tend to shy away from simple words when we want to suggest that what we are saying is important.

Comment: @BobRodes it came from the other answer I guess. People would recognize the phrase, but it sounds to me to be distinctly British. It could be that different dialects do use it, though. I think the Midwestern dialect, which is considered the most neutral dialect, does not use "cloths" in that context.

Comment: Maybe not.  But I grew up in Indiana, and it doesn't sound particularly strange to me.  Maybe a bit pretentious, like saying "pant" or "shirtings" when you're writing ads in the clothing business.